# Windows OS upgrading from 2008R2 to 2012 on SharePoint 2013 hosted servers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, upgrade, windows-server

Can Windows OS be upgraded on SharePoint hosted servers?

Will the SharePoint Farm be effected?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the Possibility**

In general scenarios, yes it's possible to upgrade the windows server from 2008 to 2012 **in-place**

**But** it's heavily recommended to do not do that on the **production** servers.

---

**Regarding the Effect**

To be honest, I don't try it before for SharepPoint farm to can specify specifically what's the effect, but based on my knowledge it for sure will effect on the farm at least there is a long downtime that may be forever!!.

---

In case you want to venture on test environment try to do the following:

- Take a full farm backup
- Take SharePoint content databases backup in case you want to use Database-Attach method.
- List all Applications service, Important configurations ....etc
- Follow the mentioned steps to upgrade [windows at Performing an in-place upgrade of Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/chrisavis/2013/10/01/performing-an-in-place-upgrade-of-server-2008-r2-to-server-2012-r2/)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in place upgrade of windows server is not supported for SharePoint servers. It is kind of full rebuild of the SharePoint farm. Check [this link.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2818510/how-to-upgrade-a-server-operating-system-that-has-sharepoint-server-2010-or-sharepoint-server-2013-installed)

- Make sure that the intended operating system is supported by the
  version of SharePoint that you are running.
- Detach the content databases from the SharePoint server.
- Uninstall SharePoint through Control Panel.
- Upgrade the operating system.
- Reinstall SharePoint.
- Attach the content databases.

If it is single server farm then above is only options. But multi server farms you can take one server out of farm rebuild it and join it to farm. This way you will have a mix os in farm for short period of time which is ok. This process will minimize the downtime.

Answer (score 0):

A method I have used is to build a new 2012R2 server, add this to the farm, then move all roles across to the new server. Once this is complete, you can remove roles from your original server, and remove it from the farm.

I have done this on multiple different environments, from a single server installation to a large farm. When working with a large farm in a Production environment, I would suggest moving one role at a time, however this depends on how much downtime you can have on the farm for backups etc.

We moved roles in the following order:

1. Central Admin
2. List item
3. Distributed Cache
4. Search
5. WFE
6. Anything else