# Upgrade our Operating System from 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 for sharepoint 2010 and 2013

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-on-prem, upgrade, windows-server-2008-r2

We have 2 sharepoint on-premises farms 2010 & 2013,which have the following architecture:-

- 2 SharePoint application servers (2010 & 2013) which are installed on Windows server 2008 R2
- 2 SQl servers 2008 R2 installed on Windows server 2008 R2.

now since windows 2008 R2 will have its end of life on January 2020. so we are planning to upgrade the OS for the sharepoint application servers (2010 & 2013) and thier database server from windows 2008 R2 to windows 2012 or 2016 R2. but i am not sure if this will be a straight formawrdward task? or we need to reconfigure or re-install the sharepoint? our on-premises farms have site collections (mainly enterprise wiki + team site), sub-sites and some farm solutions for server-side event recievers.

so i am not sure if upgrading the OS will affect the 2 sharepoint on-premises farms (2010 & 2013) ? or things on paper should work well out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never done in place upgrade for the OS on the SHarepoint server - it was too scary scenario for me. I always went with option to build new farm on new OS, reinstall custom solutions and migrate the Databases, in the end it provides the lowest downtime for the farms. (as you can rebuild everything, switch the source to read only so there are no content updates but user are still able to reach the content to do their work, then migrate databases and switch the dns to new servers, after that I decommission the old farms (after a week or so when no issues are reported from new farm).

here you have same question and some other answers for reference: [Windows OS upgrading from 2008R2 to 2012 on SharePoint 2013 hosted servers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219259/windows-os-upgrading-from-2008r2-to-2012-on-sharepoint-2013-hosted-servers)

Comment: This is the best option.  Doing an in place upgrade on the DB server can be dangerous.  You could end up currupting your content databases.  This can happen even after the process says it was successful.  The best option is outlined here.  Make you a new server and migrate your db.bak files over.  You can then upgrade your DBs from there and migrate your farm to the new OS.  Good Luck!